# Custom image for checkbox -- how to when separating the label and checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Using only CSS, I was able to replace the normal checkbox with a custom image.  The problem is, when seen on an iPad, it can look like this:

```
[] This is
some text
```

Instead of like this:

```
[] This
   some text.
```

Here's what I've got now:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

    input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: -2px 10px 0 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: url(http://qa.walkup.audidriveusa.com/images/checkbox.png) no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
        background: url(http://qa.walkup.audidriveusa.com/images/checkbox-selected.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width:100px">
   <input type="checkbox" class="SurveyQuestion" id="q6a" name="Question_Vehicle_More_Information" value="Audi_A3">
   <label for="q6a"><span></span>Audi A3 with long text that will wrap</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flex` on the parent. That will keep them on the same row, and the content will wrap in the individual flex children.

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
  height: 20px;
  margin: -2px 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
  background: url(http://qa.walkup.audidriveusa.com/images/checkbox.png) no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
  background: url(http://qa.walkup.audidriveusa.com/images/checkbox-selected.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <input type="checkbox" class="SurveyQuestion" id="q6a" name="Question_Vehicle_More_Information" value="Audi_A3">
  <label for="q6a"><span></span>Audi A3 with long text that will wrap</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Putting this on the div that wraps them both forces the checkbox and all of the label text into a 50px width

Comment: @CaseyCrookston the width is only there for the demo to show how it wraps. Updated the answer to remove that.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  We are close!  Now, for some reason, a small part of the right-hand side of the checkbox image seems to be covered up.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston can't help you with that unless I have a working demo. If you want help with that, please update your question with a demo that has working images so I can see.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I'm just guessing without a demo, and that isn't very productive for either of us. That said, you could try adding `background-size: cover; background-position: center center;` to the `span`

Comment: How do you do that Run Code thing?

Comment: Figured it out. See OP

Comment: @CaseyCrookston no the root issue was the width, that's why the background was cut off. Using `flex` (or `flex-basis`) is where a flex width should be specified. You can click the "edited" link under my answer and see the revision history of my changes to the answer.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston no sweat! glad we got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated code based on your updated code snippet:
I added `inline-flex` to the label, `padding-left: 10px` and `min-width: 20px` to the span.

```
label {
  display: inline-flex;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
  min-width: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I expect the lack of success is due to the images not being available.  Thank you for the suggestion.  The second option you give is close. It just covers up a little of the checkbox

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I updated my comment, I changed from `flex` to `inline-flex` or `inline-block` which seems to be working in my fiddle. Let me know if that is the expected behavior.

Comment: I put a code snippet in the OP that shows what I am seeing.  The checkbox should be a full box.  The text of the label is covering it up.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Updated my comment, let me know if this works. Thanks - Sam

Answer (score 0):

Integrate custom checkboxes as `<li>` of a `<ul>`

**SNIPPET**

```css
.chx {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.lbl {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px inset red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.lbl:hover {
  background: #000;
}

#chx1:checked+.lbl::before {
  content: '';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#chx2:checked+.lbl::before {
  content: '';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#chx3:checked+.lbl::before {
  content: '';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <input id='chx1' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <label for='chx1' class='lbl'></label>
  <li>Text that's long and will wrap with an indentation like a list item with a bullet.</li>

  <input id='chx2' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <label for='chx2' class='lbl'></label>
  <li>Text that's long and will wrap with an indentation like a list item with a bullet.</li>

  <input id='chx3' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <label for='chx3' class='lbl'></label>
  <li>Text that's long and will wrap with an indentation like a list item with a bullet.</li>
</ul>
```